# How to retain Cobertura ratcheted configuration in job-dsl-plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

Cobertura plugin in Jenkins has a support of ratcheting by ticking these boxes:

- Health auto update
- Stability auto update

When ticking this box, the coverage metric targets (in Jenkins configuration page) will be updated on every successful build:
[image]

These values will be overridden by job-dsl-plugin when seed job is triggered. How can I retain these values when my seed job is triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I can't find a pretty way to do this right now, but here is my solution.

**Solution**

*1. Execute a Groovy script and store all of the current job cobertura configuration in a JSON file.*

Cobertura configuration can be retrieved like:

```
def coberturaPublisher = project.getPublishersList().get(CoberturaPublisher)
coberturaPublisher.**healthyTarget**.getTarget(**CoverageMetric.METHOD**)
```

*2. job-dsl-plugin to configure cobertura by using the JSON file if it's available*

job-dsl's CoberturaContext normal method can't be called here because the data represented in the first step is different with the method parameter:

- 80% is stored as 8000000 in the JSON file
- 80% must be passed in as 80 instead of 8000000 to CoberturaContext methods.

As of today, I can't simply divide the value by 100000 because the method is accepting Integer instead of double. To retain the precision of the ratcheted configuration, I have to bypass the validation by manipulating the target directly:

```
coberturaContext.targets = [
    'METHOD': new CoberturaContext.CoberturaTarget(
        targetType: CoberturaContext.TargetType.METHOD,
        healthyTarget: 8000000,
        unhealthyTarget: previousConfig ? previousConfig.cobertura.method.unhealthy : 0,
        failingTarget: previousConfig ? previousConfig.cobertura.method.failing : 0
    ),
```

**Why bother creating the JSON file while you can call Jenkins API directly?**

My seed job is configured with this [example here](https://github.com/sheehan/job-dsl-gradle-example), hence I have an additional classpath used in the job configuration. When I tried to hit Jenkins API directly, I'm getting class loading issue for Cobertura plugin classes.